# In AngularJS, how do I use a directive to create a template with changing variable names?

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a questionnaire form using AngularJS, and I'm templatizing the different types of questions I have to keep my HTML lightweight.

HTML:

```
<qtnyesno qtn-variable="testVar">This is a test question. Yes or No?</qtnyesno>
testVar = {{testVar}}
```

JS:

```
var module = angular.module('app', [])
.directive('qtnyesno', function() {
        return {
                restrict: 'E', // must be an HTML element
                transclude: true,
                scope: {
                        valvar: '@qtnVariable',
                },
                template:
                    '<div>' +
                    '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
                    '<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="rdo{{valvar}}" value="1" ng-model="{{valvar}}">Yes </label>' +
                    '<label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="rdo{{valvar}}" value="0" ng-model="{{valvar}}">No </label>' +
                    '<hr></div>',
                replace: true,
        };
});
```

When I use within the input tag *ng-model="{{valvar}}"* I get compilation errors.

When I try using instead *ng-click="{{valvar}} = 0"* I get no compilation errors, but my display statement to get the value of testVar never works when I click on the radio buttons.

**How would I fix this such that the last line of my HTML gets properly updated with the value of testVar when I click on the buttons?**

I'm using AngularJS along with Bootstrap.  I'm fairly new to both frameworks, so I'm not sure if this is even the best way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon's right, use `=` in your isolate scope to get the two-way binding, but there's one more thing you have to do: remove the curly braces from around your `ng-model` declarations.

`ng-model` declarations take an angular expression and evaluate them in the scope, so there's no need for the braces to force evaluation. In fact, the braces will mess things up.

```
// so just
ng-model="valvar"
```

[Here's a fiddle with your code with these changes](http://jsfiddle.net/2PPLa/).

Comment: One question I just thought of -- how does the name attribute for the radio button get interpreted?  In neither Safari or Chrome dev tools the variable appears as rdo + the name of the variable being given.

Answer (score 1):

To get bi-directional binding in your isolate scope, use `=`:

```
scope: {
  valvar: '=qtnVariable',
},
```

`@` makes the resulting scope variable a string with interpolation.

Comment: I tried this using ng-click instead of ng-model in my template.  There are no compilation errors; however, in my generated HTML in my browser (when I look in FireBug) valvar is replaced with an empty string.  When I was using ng-click previously, the variables were getting written into the correct places in the HTML, but for some reason AngularJS wasn't performing any of its magic on that code versus the rest of the HTML document.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle example or something similar to demonstrate the issue?